# Proportional or exponential increase?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I'm reading an economics textbook and I have the following doubt (that is about maths):

Let us consider the following equation(that I guess is the particular solution of a differential equation):

$q(j,t) = \lambda^{n(j,t)}q(j,0)$ , with $\lambda > 1$

$q(j,t)$ denotes the quality of a machine $j$ at time t, with $j \in [0,1]$ (we assume there exists a unit continuum of machines).

and $n(j,t)$ denotes the number of innovations occurred on machine $j$ from time **zero** to $t$.

This equation is telling us that the quality of a $j$ machine at time $t$ depends on the cumulative number of innovations that occurred up to time $t$.
This notation implies that there is a quality ladder for each machine variety, and each innovation pushes the machine quality up by one rung on this ladder. These rungs are proportionally equidistant so that each innovation leads to a proportional increase in quality by an amount $\lambda >1$.

That is what is claimed by the book, i.e. a proportional equidistant increase in quality for any innovation. However, I see an exponential increase in quality for any innovation.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > $q(j,t) = \lambda^{n(j,t)}q(j,0),$ with $\lambda > 1$

The parameter $j$ is being fixed, so we can just write that for $\lambda>1,$ $$\large q = q_0\lambda^{n_t}.$$

This means that, for positive $q_0,$ $q$ is growing exponentially with respect to $n;$ that is, $q$ is undergoing constant percentage increase with respect to $n.$

> > each innovation leads to a proportional increase in quality by an amount $\lambda.$

This claim translates as $$\large q=\lambda n_t+q_0,$$ which says that $q$ is increasing linearly with respect to $n.$

> However, I see an exponential increase in quality for any innovation.

Yes.

Comment: Crystal clear. Thanks